# How to convert input integers into text output? (ex. input: 12. output: "one two")

Tags: c

Beginner C student and was assigned with creating a program that let's user enter a 5-digit zip code. The program must ensure user enters exactly 5 digits otherwise the program will tell the number of digits entered and asks until exactly 5 are entered. Once 5 digits are entered, the program will output the number into text.

I am unsure on how to proceed with the converting digit into text part of the problem. Here is my work so far...

My code so far..

```
int main(void) {
    int userIn;
    int digitCount = 0;

    printf("Enter a 5 digit-zip code: \n");
    scanf("%d", &userIn);

    if (userIn <= 0) {
        printf("Entered incorrect zip code!\n");
    }
    else {
        while (userIn > 0) {
            userIn /= 10;
            digitCount++;
        }
        if (digitCount == 5) {      // Convert digits to text
            int firstDig = digitCount % 10;
            int digNum;
            if (firstDig > 0 && firstDig < 10) {
                switch (digNum) {
    
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("you entered %d digits\n", digitCount);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

As you can see, I've been able to make a program that counts the number of digits entered if not 5 although I'm still unsure about the method used to count the digits as it is not good for finding the number of large integers. However, I believe I will be able to figure out a more efficient method.

Where I am running into a problem is where I have to convert the 5-digit number into text. Some help as to how to approach this problem would be appreciated!

Comment: Pro tip: just because it's made of digits or called a number does not mean it's best represented in your program via a numeric data type.  If it's of interest mainly as a sequence of digits, then its often to your advantage to use a string, instead.

Comment: If you need to map digits to strings then one natural technique would be to write a lookup table into your program.  That is, create an array of the digit names you want to use, in order.  Take each digit you want to convert, convert it to the corresponding index, and read the string from your array via that index.  Do be mindful, however, that the numeric values of the digit *characters* are not the same as the place values of the digits.

Comment: `while (userIn > 0) {` will not work for zip codes like [00501](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code#:~:text=The%20lowest%20ZIP%20Code%20is,Internal%20Revenue%20Service%20center%20there).) as that will only count 3 digits.  Better to receive input as a _string_.  Research `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

When needing to perform some type of specific value length, often times it is best to work with the value as a string as opposed to a number/integer.  Once all validation has been cleared, then the string value can usually be converted to a numeric value.

With that in mind following is a refactored version of your program offering the required checks for proper zip code length and ensurance that only digits were entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char userInput[10];
    int userIn;
    int test;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a 5 digit-zip code: \n");
        userIn = scanf("%s", userInput);
        test = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (userInput[i] == '\n')
            {
                userInput[i] = '\0';        /* Strip the newline character from the string          */
                break;
            }
        }

        if (strlen(userInput) != 5)         /* Five characters were not entered - display error     */
        {
            printf("An incorrect number of digits were entered - try again!\n");
            continue;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (userInput[i] < '0' || userInput[i] > '9')
            {
                printf("A non-digit character was entered - try again!\n");
                test = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (test > 0)   /* A value of "1" indicates that a non-digit character was found and a retry is needed  */
            continue;

        userIn = atoi(userInput);   /* If this point is reached, a valid zip code was entered                   */
        break;
    }

    printf("The following zip code was entered - %s\nand its integer equivalent is: %d\n", userInput, userIn);

    return 0;
}
```

The key points to note are:

- User input is a character array (a string) as opposed to the entry of an integer.
- The length of the entered value is checked to ensure that its length is five characters.
- Since it would be possible for the user to enter non-digit characters, an additional test is performed to ensure that the characters are the digits "0" to "9".
- All of the input and validation is wrapped inside a "while" loop to allow for retries by the user to enter a valid zip code.
- Once a valid zip code is entered, the string input can be converted to an integer value if needed.

With those additional bits, following was some test output.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Zipcode/bin/Release$ ./Zipcode 
Enter a 5 digit-zip code: 
eeeee
A non-digit character was entered - try again!
Enter a 5 digit-zip code: 
222
An incorrect number of digits were entered - try again!
Enter a 5 digit-zip code: 
444444
An incorrect number of digits were entered - try again!
Enter a 5 digit-zip code: 
58047
The following zip code was entered - 58047
and its integer equivalent is: 58047
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Zipcode/bin/Release$ ./Zipcode 
Enter a 5 digit-zip code: 
00501
The following zip code was entered - 00501
and its integer equivalent is: 501
```

This set of tests also drive home the point that zip codes can start with a leading zero (or zeros).

So, the takeaway is that for some types of numeric validations, it may be appropriate to evaluate input as a character array first and then convert the input to a numeric value.  You might want to also reference tutorial literature on the usage of character arrays.

Comment: Avoid `%s`.  Instead used a _width_ like `%9s` in this case to avoid over-runs.  Even better, consider `fgets()`.

Comment: `userInput[i] == '\n'` is _never_ true when reading with `scanf("%s", userInput)` as `"%s"` does not save white-space.

Comment: You save the return value of `scanf()` in `userIn`, but never check it. And what should the variable's name mean in contrast to `userInput`? If you try to help beginners, at least use reasonable names.